# What is $MFT file and can the size be reduced?

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, wiztree

I use WizTree to check why my disk space is shrinking without reason, and I found that there is this $MFT (hidden) file, which consumes 8++ GB.

[image]

What is this? And is there anyway I can reduce the size of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Mft is the NTFS "Master File Table" – it's the file which holds all information about *what files you have and where they are physically.*

You seem to have about 8 million files, so assuming a ~1 kB metadata entry per file, an 8 GB $Mft is entirely reasonable.

Comment: So it seems like the only way to reduce $MFT file size is to delete files, be them in C or D drive?

Comment: Yes, although I'm not sure whether the MFT *can* be shrunk at all, but if it cannot, then still the only way to avoid having it grow is to avoid creating so many files. (After all, the filesystem has to keep track of those files *somehow*...) No, the D: drive has nothing to do with it – whether it's a different physical disk or just a different partition, either way it's a separate filesystem that has its own $Mft (or equivalent).

Comment: Back up before you mess with the MFT.

Comment: @user1686 MFT won't shrink when files get deleted. See third paragraph under "More Information": https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/ntfs-reserves-space-for-mft